# How can I narrow down this query by using the max function?

Tags: mysql, sql

[image: Incorrect Query Result]

I am using PHP MyAdmin. I want the result of this query to be Willard Wildcats and 7, but I can't figure out how to do it by using the max function rather than the order by and limit functions. I need to use the max function

```
Select Team_Name, Count(*)
From Number_3
Group By Team_Name
```

The result of this query should be

```
Willard Wildcats and 7
```

Comment: Hint:  `ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC LIMIT 1`.

Comment: My instructor does not want me to use the limit function. I need to use the max function

Answer (score 1):

Use `LIMIT` clause :

```
SELECT Team_Name, Count(*) AS CNT 
FROM Number_3
GROUP BY Team_Name
ORDER BY CNT DESC
LIMIT 1;
```

If you are limited with `LIMIT` clause then use subquery :

```
SELECT Team_Name, Count(*) AS CNT 
FROM Number_3
GROUP BY Team_Name
HAVING Count(*) = (SELECT MAX(CNT)
                   FROM (SELECT Team_Name, Count(*) AS CNT 
                         FROM Number_3
                         GROUP BY Team_Name
                        ) t
                  );
```

If you are working latest version of `MySQL` then it will be more easier with ranking function :

```
SELECT t.*
FROM (SELECT Team_Name, Count(*) AS CNT,
             DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY Count(*) DESC) AS Seq 
      FROM Number_3
      GROUP BY Team_Name
     ) t
WHERE Seq = 1;
```

Comment: My instructor does not want me to use the limit function. I need to use the max function

Comment: Wouldn't ordering be less efficient than using `MAX`?

Comment: @Joseph, click the checkmark next to the up/down votes so others know this worked.  Also, pass back to your instructor what IF there are multiple teams with tied wins..  You would only get 1, but I understand they are trying to get you to understand the PURPOSE of the limit clause.

Answer (score 1):

You need to write where condition and select a column using max function

```
Select Team_Name, Count(*) From Number_3 where Team_Name=(select max(Count(*)) from Number_3)
```